# CSS top-left quarter circle menu

Tags: css-transforms

I've slowly been trying to make a top-left quarter-circle menu using CSS transforms, here is my HTML:

```html
<header>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Seems that there are at least three or more things that have to be simultaneously done and I've only got the rough of it. My goal is to make the menus *match* the area of the black `header` element as closely as possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/8axqpen4/